# How have character styles conveyed to index entries in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm getting ready to index a book about computer programming. Many index entries will have words that should be styled with my "Code" character style, but I have not been able to find out how I can apply character styles to parts of index entries (in some cases only parts of words).

If I apply character styling to the text in the index entry's XE field, the resulting index entry doesn't reflect it. If I add the styled text I want in an index entry to the text of the book, highlight it and use the Mark Index Entry dialog to create an index entry, that simply creates an XE field with the styling applied, but the resulting index entry again lacks the styling.

Help?